# When changing the value of a variable in C, is a new primitive created or is the current primitive mutated?

Tags: java, objective-c, c, primitive, mutable

I know that 'mutable' and 'immutable' are terms that should be used to describe the ability for objects to change value in object oriented languages such as Java and Objective C. However, I would like to bring it up because it relates to my question regarding primitives data. I know that when I change the value of a variable holding immutable object, I am in fact creating a new object. I wonder, however, if primitives data in C behave similarly to immutable objects. By that I mean, when I change the value of a variable holding primitive data, a new data is created and referenced by the variable. Or do the existing primitives actually mutated/modified the stored data values?

**Edit #1:**

**Issue #1:** I would like to clear up some misunderstandings (either on my part or on others) because I did not make it clear when I said "when I change the value of a variable holding immutable object, I am in fact creating a new object." When I said that, I did not mean to assign the variable to an existing object. For example:

```
// Example 1: I did not mean this
-------------------------
String x = "Hello World";
String y = x;
-------------------------

// Example 2: What I meant is this
-------------------------
String x = "Hello World";
//This will print out "Hello World"
System.out.println(x);

x = "Goodbye World";
//This will print out "Goodbye World"
System.out.println(x);
-------------------------
```

Of course, assigning variable y to variable x as in Example 1, which was the case you guys brought up, only reference variable y to the object that x is referencing. Of course, in this scenario, there is no new object; just the same object “Hello World” being referenced by 2 variables.

What I meant is when x = “Goodbye World” in Example 2, the variable x is referencing a new String object with the values “Goodbye World”, instead, of the first String object “Hello World” that x was initialized with. String is an Immutable object in Java. The only way to change the values for a String variable is to let the variable reference an existing object **OR** a new String object. If there is no existing object (“Goodbye World” String object has not been created anywhere), then the above code just created a new String object and reference x to it. Am I right? If not, please correct me.

**Issue #2:** I would like to sum up the answers, especially one from **Ulfalizer**:

1) There are actually 2 forms in which variable can exist:

a) “Memory Address” - this is the case for variables in C language, as well as Java and Objective C in regard to primitive-type data. For instance: int x = 1. The variable x here is an actual memory address itself, which has type integer and is initialized with the value 1.

b) “Reference” - this is the case for most variables in Java, in regard to non-primitive-type data (objects). For instance: String x = “Hello World”. The variable x is just a pointer/reference to ‘a memory address existing somewhere’, which holds the value “Hello World” as its content.

2) Variables for primitive-type data in C, Java, and Objective C behave as “Memory Address”. Hence, when I do this:

```
-------------------------
int x = 10;
x = 2;
-------------------------
```

The value of x variable (aka - memory address) is actually changed from 10 to 2. In other words, value stored in “Memory Address” variables can be modified/changed.

3) In C language, a variable can also behave as a reference if it is declared with ‘*’ - pointer type. I will use **Ulfalizer**’s example: int *ptr. ptr is a pointer variable that can point to another variable (aka memory address) such as: ptr = &x. If x is initialized as: int x = 10, then x is an actual memory address that holds the value 10. So in the codes below

```
-------------------------
int x;
int *ptr;
ptr = &x;
*ptr = 1;
-------------------------
```

I can actually modified the value stored in x variable (aka - memory address) through the ptr pointer-variable.

Please confirm if my interpretations are correct/false. Thank you.

Comment: Realise that there is, even in Java, a difference between an Object and a primitive data type. And that the primitives aren't immutable.

Comment: If you think that changing a variable value creates a new object in any of the languages you mentioned, then I suggest you do some more study.

Comment: "I know that when I change the value of a variable holding immutable object, I am in fact creating a new object"--no, not true in Java.  For non-primitives, variables are just references.  If you change the value of a variable, you're making it point to a different object.  But a method you call might create a new object.  `String s1 = "abc"; s1 = s2;` The assignment does not create a new object.  `s1 = s1.substring(2, 3);`--the `substring` method creates the new object, not the assignment.

Comment: @ajb - Could you please check the Issue #1 above?

Comment: A "primitive" is something like `int` or `double` or `char`.  You seem (at least in the first part of your question) to be talking about "objects", not "primitives".

Comment: @HotLicks - that's my bad, I was trying to bring the concept of mutable/immutable from objects and make a connection to what I want to know regarding primitives - their modifiability.

Comment: I stand by what I said.  If you say `variable = expression`, the expression potentially creates a new object.  The assignment has nothing to do with it.  And in the case `x = "Goodbye world"`, it assigns `x` to an existing object.  The existing object was created earlier, when the program was first run, because that's what happens with constant strings in Java.  The assignment does not create a new object.

Comment: @ajb - You seem to not understand what i wrote at all even after my attempt to explain it a second time. You are the one who keep interpret that I said the 'assignment created the object'. Since when did i say that? I explain the my statement which you misinterpreted in the Issue #1. Do you or do you not agree with what I said in Issue #1?

Comment: "when I change the value of a variable ... I am in fact creating a new object".  That implies that you think creating a new object has something to do with changing a variable.  It doesn't. The expression on the right side of `=` is what creates the new object, same as if you used the same expression in a statement that didn't assign the result to anything.

Comment: @ajb - Did you even read the Issue #1? Whatever you just said was just YOURS ASSUMPTION. I did not imply anything and Issue #1 explained EXACTLY what i meant with concrete examples. Instead of checking my Issue #1 and give constructive comments, which i am genuinely looking forward to, you are just repeating yourself. Thank you, I am done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to understand how C works is to think of it as high-level assembly language. Variables are simply locations in memory, and assigning a value to a variable stores the value into that location. From a high-level language perspective, that would be mutation in its purest form.

In C, a declaration/definition like

```
int x;
```

tells the compiler to reserve some memory for the `int` variable `x`. (Inside a function, the memory would come from the stack. At global scope, it would come from the data segment.)

An assignment like

```
x = 7;
```

simply generates code to copy the value 7 into that memory location. Similarly, an assignment like

```
x = y;
```

generates code to copy the `int` value stored at `y`'s memory location into `x`'s memory location. (Assume `y` is another `int`.)

The same logic also holds for more complex types than `int`s.

In Java, variables are references instead (for non-primitive types anyway), and can refer to different objects at different times. To get something similar to references in C, you have to explicitly define a *pointer* variable -- a variable that holds an address -- and point it to (assign it the address of) different objects at different times.

*(I included the below example just in case you're interested.)*

The `&` operator is used to get the address of a variable in C, so that `&x` would be the address of `x` for example. The `*` operator gives the pointed-to object when applied to a pointer. Here's an example of how a pointer could be used to refer to different variables at different times:

```
int x;
int y;
/* Declares 'ptr' as a pointer, and says that it points to an int.
   The pointed-to type is used by the compiler for type checking
   and type conversions. */
int *ptr;

ptr = &x; // Store the address of 'x' in 'ptr'.
*ptr = 1; // Store 1 into the memory 'ptr' points to ('x').
ptr = &y; // Store the address of 'y' in 'ptr'.
*ptr = 2; // Store 2 into the memory 'ptr' points to ('y').
```

The end result of the above code would be to set `x` to 1 and `y` to 2. This is a silly example of course, but hopefully it should get the idea across.

(C99 and later support `//`-style comments by the way.)

## Answers for issues

*(Caveat: My Java is a bit rusty, so I had to do some reading up. Hopefully the details should be correct. Feel free to correct me.)*

### Issue #1

The assignment

```
x = "Goodbye World";
```

would have the effect of making `x` refer to a `String` object with the value "Goodbye world". Exactly *when* this `String` object is created shouldn't make a difference, as long as it's created before it's assigned to `x` (or any other variable).

It might be created just before the assignment is executed, or when the program starts. Normally you wouldn't be able to tell the difference.

### Issue #2

It sounds like you have the high-level concepts down, and your C code is correct.

(It's more correct to say that "`ptr` is a pointer" than to say that "`*ptr` is a pointer" though. There's some syntactic obscurity in C that makes it more natural to put the `*` next the name in the declaration (IMO), but you can also write the declaration like `int* ptr;` for that case. Things only start to get weird when you declare many variables in the same line.)

When talking about how Java is implemented, references might have to be a bit more advanced than just pointers to objects under the hood. For example, the JVM might move objects around in memory (which would change their address) to reduce memory fragmentation, but references must still remain valid. One way to do it would be to "fix" pointers whenever objects are moved, another to have references be indices into a table of pointers instead. Regardless of how it's done in the JVM implementation, *pointer* is the right thinking at least.

Since each reference in Java has a pointer field (at a high level, ignoring exactly how the implementation does it), and since this field isn't needed for primitive types, one possibility is to reuse the pointer field and store the value in it instead for primitive types.

For example, an assignment like

```
x = 1;
```

might store the value 1 directly into the pointer field of the reference `x`. Techniques like this are pretty common.

As a side note, a `union` can be used to in C to store two different types (e.g., an `int` and a pointer) in the same place in memory so that they overlap. Of course, assigning to one of the types would change the value for the other type too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanations are very clear and the last example is perfect. Would you please take a look at my interpretation of your answer above (Issue #2, but I would love to hear your opinion on Issue #1 too :) )? Really appreciate it.

Comment: @langtutheky: Thanks! I added answers for the issues too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a small question: When you want to assign a pointer to another pointer, I would not need the asterisk in front right? Example: int x = 10; int *a; *a = x; int *b; b = a. This would make b point to the same address as pointer a right? The reason I am asking this is to explain the Objective C notation: NSString *x = @"Hello"; x = @"World". In the Objective C case, I believe the *x is a pointer and @"World" is another pointer. That could explain why x = @"World" is legal in Objective C, instead of *x = @"World".

Comment: @langtutheky: Correct. If `x` and `y` are pointers, then `x = y` would copy the address stored in `y` to `x`, so that they point to the same place after that. You only do `*ptr` when you want to access the value the pointer points to.

Comment: I don't know Objective C, but that sounds plausible at least. :)

Comment: Note that you should do `a = &x;` and not `*a = x;` if you want to assign the address of `x` to `a` though. `*a = x` would store the value of `x` to the `int` that `a` points to (to the address stored in `a`). `*a` reads as "the thing `a` points to", `&x` means "the address of `x`". (They probably chose `&` because both "ampersand" and "address" start with an *a*.)

Comment: Thank you again for picking that up. That was a typo, I was typing in a rush :P.

Comment: @langtutheky: Yeah, guessed it was a typo. It was a "just in case" explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be the current primitive modified. I tested using a simple code [here](http://ideone.com/kO3DSo), and it refers to the same address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int a = 5;

    printf ("%p = %i\n", (void*) &a, a);
    a = 10;
    printf ("%p = %i\n", (void*) &a, a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer - "current primitive modified" but I was hoping for a more thorough explanation.