# Modify code to pass by reference

Tags: c, pointers

```
void square(int num) {
num = num * num;
}

int main()
{
int x = 4;
square(x);
printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

I've been given this code, it's supposed to give answer '16' by squaring my integer 'x'.

However, I've been asked to modify the code to "pass by reference".

I've tried a fair few things here and there and can't see any other options to get this code running without errors such as "invalid operands to binary" or "invalid type argument of 'unary *' "

this is what I've got currently:

```
void square(int* num) {
     *num = num * num;
}

int main()
{
    int* x = 4;
    square(&x);
    printf("%d\n", x);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make that `int x = 4;` and do `*num = (*num) * (*num);` (with some parentheses for clarity, or just do `*num *= *num`) inside the function. Not meant to sound snarky, but the best use of your time would probably be to find a basic reference on how pointers work, as you don't seem to have it down. They're not really something you can "guess" your way to.

Comment: I realise I can't guess my way through, I've read a lot of material on it, I'm just trying to get a better understanding through some exercises. This has been most eye opening.

Comment: This is a shameless self-plug, but maybe this answer could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29247824/when-changing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-c-is-a-new-primitive-created-or-is-the/29248076#29248076. It's C contrasted with Java in that case, but it might be useful purely for understanding how C works too.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change

```
 int* x = 4;
```

to

```
 int x = 4;
```

because, `x` is of type `int` and `&x` will be of type `int *`, which you need to pass to `square()`.

Then, inside the `square()`, you need to use

```
*num = *num * *num;  //*num === type int, num == type int *
```

Note: it's recommended to use `int main(void)` as the function prototype.

Comment: It still seems to have a problem with my *num = num * num; line. Giving me the 2nd error I described in OP

Comment: Thank you! why is void recommended?

Comment: @GeorgeOthen it's the `C` standard. It makes sure no command line arguments are read by your application. :-)